# What is the precedence of ~, and why?

Tags: haskell

The following snippet compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
type family Foo a b

f :: (Foo a b ~ Int) => a -> b -> b
f = error ""
```

but *infix* type operators seem to behave differently:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
type family a \\ b

f :: (a \\ b ~ Int) => a -> b -> b
f = error ""
```

GHC complains that the second argument to `\\` should have kind `*`, but `b ~ Int` has kind `Constraint`. Of course this can be fixed with parens, but I'm wondering if there's another way.

I've tried setting the precedence of my operator with the fixity declaration `infixl 9 \\`, but that doesn't fix the problem, indicating that the precedence of `~` is [at least 9](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.4.2) (if I'm interpreting that correctly). I tried using the trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27099641/925978) to make GHCi tell me the precedence of `~`, but it didn't work.

Technically speaking, `~` probably isn't a type operator, it's more of a lexical construct similar to `,`, but the questions still stand:

1. Why do infix and prefix operators exhibit different behavior?
2. Why does `~` bind so tightly?
3. Is there something I can do to make my own operators bind even tighter?

(Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27096277/925978) asks about the precedence of type functions, but it doesn't say anything about `~`.)

Comment: Another odd thing is that if I ask GHCi `:k (~)`, it tells me `(~) :: k -> k -> Constraint`, but if I ask `:i (~)`, it tells me `parse error on input ‘~’`. So something seems to be very strange about how the parser handles `~`.

Comment: I'm not certain what the cause of this is - `~` has some special behaviors due to being a built-in type function, and maybe it should be consistent with other things. But if this really bothers you, you can do something like `type (==) = (~); infixr 0 ==`, which would even be more syntactically consistent between term and type level.

Comment: I've got a [GHC ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10056) now

Answer (score 1):

`~` isn't an operator, it's a keyword, like `module` or `case`, so I think you could only alter the precedence using parentheses.

See more here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.7E

Comment: That's clearly not the whole story. Yes, `~` in a pattern is syntax, but in other contexts it's a type operator.

Comment: It seems like a type operator because you can get its kind, but isn't it possible it just *acts* like one?

Comment: I'm not skilled enough to comb the source for the implementation,  but that's what I suspect.